# Cute version of "sleep together"

Tags: phrase-requests, connotation

The expression "sleep together" has a sexual context, but I'm looking for the expression when two or more people are literally sleeping together. Is there such an expression? The usage would be for cute fictional character stories.

> They both climbed into the bed, snuggled up like cats and slept together.

Comment: "They both climbed into the bed, snuggled up like cats and slept."

Comment: Simple *slept* or *fell asleep* will do; if, nevertheless, you want to emphasize their proximity, you might use *slept side by side* or *slept beside each other*.

Comment: You could try: bunking with someone (more like summer camp in my eyes), shack up (could be sexual if in a certain context), or just nip it in the bud and say, "They both climbed into bed, snuggled up like cats, and snored loudly until the sun came up."

Comment: Anonym has the solution! But how would I rewrite this?: "Let's sleep together in my bed!"

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that felines and cuteness make this very distinct from the other question. >_>

Anyway I'd put it like this:

> They both climbed into the bed, snuggled up like kittens and took a catnap together.

Or if you really have your heart set on cats, perhaps just a nap because using cat twice just sounds bit redundant. The only problem is that a nap is generally supposed to be considered short but as a lifelong cat owner myself, well, let's just say they get plentiful amounts of sleep.

Comment: The problem is that the felines in question are anthros and the internet is dirty regarding anthros.

Comment: @Foxcat385 Are you San Renard? =P Anyway, no amount of semantics can fix readership bias since it's propensity inherent to the mind. A lewdster could interpret anything lewdly which's half of why there are so many erotic euphemisms (The other half is shame), including "[sex](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sex)" incidentally if you check the etymological history of that word.  That's why there is allegedly no impunity from Rule 34, as I'm sure you know. Though you might be able to minimize these connotations, I think they're inescapable. If you can correct me, I'd like to know though.

Comment: No? Why would I be?